# Showing a dialog from a separate html file and passing it a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am using android 2.2, phonegap 1.3, and jquery-mobile 1.0

I have a list view in which there is an element in the list that I want to use to create a dialog. I would like my dialog to be defined in a separate file so I can reuse it and I would like it to set the title according to the value I pass.

My dialog looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#title").append(SMSPLUS.queryString("title"));
});
</script>
<title>Dialog</title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" class="ui-page-z">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="z" class="ui-bar-z">
    <h1 id="title"></h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using a #href with the title parameter (as defined below), dialog is opened  but the title param isn't present.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
    ...
    <li><a href="dialog.html?title=blah" data-rel="dialog"/></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I have read that I could use a `data-url` but in this case it is not clear where I define it (in the `<a>` or in a `<div>` which wraps it)  and how I extract this in the dialog page.

**EDIT**

For the record the mechanism works in a standard browser but without the styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the script inside the `<script>` tags below which listens for page show events and updates the title and placeholder for the input.

```
<div data-role="page" class="ui-page-z">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="z" class="ui-bar-z">
        <h1 id="title">
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <input placeholder="Type here..." id="configtext">
        </input>

    ...

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("div.ui-page-z").live("pageshow", function(event, ui) {
            var dataUrl = $(".ui-page-active").attr("data-url");
            $("#title").empty();
            $("#title").append(SMSPLUS.getValue("title", dataUrl));
            $("#configtext").attr("placeholder", SMSPLUS.getValue("placeholder", dataUrl));
                    });
    </script>
</div>
```

The script wasn't detected when placed in the header (presumably because the framework takes no notice of headers for dialogs)

Answer (score 0):

You might try removing the

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#title").append(SMSPLUS.queryString("title"));
});
</script>
<title>Dialog</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

and only return the body html & javascript in your ajax call. Having two DOMS in one might confuse the browser.

Comment: Says in the docs dialogs should be defined as a complete html doc